# What is the Purpose of the Item type in Foundation

Tags: haskell, types

Both the following compile fine with Foundation (and Prelude as qualified import P) and return the expected string.

```
-- the inferred type
blahhh :: Item [Char]
blahhh = P.head $ toList ("blahh de blahh de blahh" :: [Item [Char]])

blahh2 :: [Char]
blahh2 = blahhh : ": Should be a b"
```

and

```
blahhh :: Char
blahhh = P.head $ toList ("blahh de blahh de blahh" :: [Char])

blahh2 :: [Char]
blahh2 = blahhh : ": Should be a b"
```

I found this a bit confusing at first. I initially thought there was some `Item` data type I needed to pattern match against within the list.

I then realised that `Item` extracts the item type from the the list (as documented), so `Item [Char] == Char`.

My question is what is the purpose of this (`Item`) and similar such types? What does the extra complexity buy you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're right that `Item` just adds complexity when using `[Char]`. However, the idea behind `Item` is that it can be used for other types as well. For instance, `Item (Array ty)` is `ty`, `Item CSV` is `Row`, `Item Bitmap` is `Bool` etc. This makes our functions more polymorphic so they may be used more generally: for instance, take `fromList :: [Item l] -> l`, which may be used in any of the following situations depending on what `l` is:

```
fromList :: [a]    -> [a]
fromList :: [ty]   -> Array ty
fromList :: [Row]  -> CSV
fromList :: [Bool] -> Bitmap
```

Which is easier to use than having a bunch of functions `fromListArray`, `fromRowsCSV` etc.

Answer (score 2):

`Item` isn't a normal type, but a "type synonym family" (poorly named), which is a sort of type-level function. `type instance Item [a] = a`as you saw means you can replace occurrences (in type signatures) of "`Item [a]`", with "`a`", much like the function declaration `snd (_,y) = y` means you can replace "`snd (1,2)`" with "`2`".

The point of `Item a` is it lets you write code that is *generic with respect to the argument `a`*. Or rather it lets you express the type of such a function.

Usually for a type synonym family like this to be useful it needs to be paired with a type class: the latter lets you define different *behavior* over different types, the former allows, say, an output type to depend on the type of the input. Multiparameter type-classes + functional dependencies accomplish the same goal.

Sometimes type families are (again, confusingly) called "associated types" when they are defined as part of a type class (due to the relationship described in paragraph above), but this is a shallow syntactic thing.

Traditionally type families were "open" (like typeclasses), but there are now closed type families which can be helpful for recursion.